# Old asymptote code in LaTeX document does not work after asymptote upgrad

Tags: asymptote

I have a LaTeX-document with embedded Asymptote code that works fine. That is, in Asymptote 2.15.
When I upgraded to 2.32 and rerun, the program gets stuck on working on one of the graphs. Stuck, no error messages or termination.
If I run the corresponding asymptote code separately it works fine. If, however, I try to run the file produced in the process, xxx-n.asy, it gets stuck in the same way.
It appears that it is one of the lines

```
if(!settings.multipleView) settings.batchView=false;
settings.tex="pdflatex";
settings.inlinetex=true;
settings.inlineimage=true;
```

that causes the problem. But I cannot figure out which, and more importantly, why.
What has happened between versions 2.15 and 2.32 that I have missed and would explain this.

On request, here is a sample file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\title{A test example}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}  
\begin{document}  
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Some introductory text.

\begin{center}
\begin{asy}
import graph3;
import solids;
size(100);
currentprojection=orthographic(5,3,2);
revolution sphere=sphere(1);
draw(surface(sphere),green+opacity(0.2),nv=5);
draw(arc((0,0,0),1,90,0,90,60,CCW)--arc((0,0,0),1,90,60,0,60,CCW)--arc((0,0,0),1,0,0,90,0)--cycle,red+2);
draw(circle((0,0,0),1,(0,0,1)));
draw(arc((0,0,0.9),0.1,10,0,10,60));
label("$\alpha$",(0,0,.8));
\end{asy}
\end{center}
More text
\end{document}
```

Comment: For a question requiring this depth of understanding of Asymptote settings, you may be better off asking on the [Asymptote forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/asymptote/discussion/409349).

Comment: Could you try to compile your document in an new empty directory and give an ECM ? Please also specify your OS.

Comment: My OS is Windows 7 professional. Unfortunately I do not know what an ECM is. How do I give one?

Comment: Please give the latex file with the problematic asy graphs. Sorry ECM is "exemple concret minimal" (in french).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the file. I have no problem to compile your example (Linux 64, svn2.33 almost the 2.32 version). In a new directory, can you try your not-working example and give the example-1.asy file ? Can you verify that the asymptote.sty is the good one ? And what happens with `asy -vv ` command on the not working asy file ? `asy -vv` will give more details. Perhaps stackexchange is not the right place and that the asymptote help forum should be a better place to experiment.